# Como faço para não perder as linhas da minha GridView que foram criadas dinamicamente no RowDataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Aqui esta a Grid montada corretamente]

A grid já esta sendo montada corretamente. Porem quando eu dou um PostBack clicando em algum botão na pagina, a grid se mantém e apenas os cabeçalhos (linhas em roxo) somem.
Sei que se eu chamar o método para recarregar a grid novamente, funciona, mas não me parece algo bom de se fazer.

Código para criação dos cabeçalhos dinâmicos.

```
  protected void grvAvaliacao_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //Se mudar o Head
                if (!DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "NAT_Nome").Equals(Session["Competencia"]))
                {
                    Session["Competencia"] = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "NAT_Nome");
                    this.head = true;
                }

                if (this.head)
                {
                    GridViewRow linha = CriarCabecalho(e);

                    //linha -> tabela
                    var tabela = e.Row.Parent as Table;
                    tabela.Rows.AddAt(tabela.Rows.Count - 1, linha);

                    this.head = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Adiciona o código do Page_Load. Lá tem que verificar se !IsPostBack. [Ficou bonita esta interface gráfica / tabela]

Comment: Ola Tony! Sim lá eu já faço essa verificação, porem o carregamento da minha grid é no evento de um botão.

Answer (score -1):

Deixe a criação dos cabeçalhos em outros eventos, como o [`RowCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) e o [`RowCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
protected void grvAvaliacao_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    // Coloque aqui a criação dos cabeçalhos
}

protected void grvAvaliacao_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    // Coloque aqui a criação dos cabeçalhos
}
```

Comment: Ola Cigano! Eu tentei implementar as suas 2 sugestões e obtive os seguintes problemas: No RowCommand, se eu criar os cabeçalhos lá, eles são apareceram quando eu clicar em algo. No RowCreate, eu perco o GridViewRowEventArgs que eu uso para popular uma coluna de cabeçalho (GridViewRow linha = CriarCabecalho(e);).

Comment: @alexanderPataki Você tentou deixar nos três eventos ao mesmo tempo?